# Backfeed breaker use

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm going to install a Eaton BRMLKCSR lockout on a Eaton BR816 B200 RF panel can i use a regular 240 v breaker or is a special backfeed breaker required to connect the generator?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### You can use a regular BR2xx (two pole) breaker for this

As you can see in the picture below just to the right of the breaker's UL mark, Eaton BR two-pole breakers have the screwhole required by the BR backfeed retainer kit as a stock feature of the breaker frame:

[image: a BR250]

As a result, you can simply use a two-pole Eaton BR breaker of the appropriate amp rating for this, given your current hardware constraints.  (It won't be 100% Code unless you pull the N-G bond out of your genset, but it won't zap any linesmen, at least!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular 240v breaker as long as it's fully compatible with the panel and the mechanical interlock.